# Radiobuttons events in wpf

Tags: wpf, events, radio-button

There are two radiobuttons. On each I have set eventhandlers for Checked and Unchecked. When radio1 is checked and I set radio2, event handler for uncheck radio1 doesn't run, only event handler for check radio2. How can I run both of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those events only reflect user interaction, if you want to catch all changes you might want to bind `IsChecked` on both RadioButtons to respective properties, then you can subscribe to a [`PropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx) event to get all changes. (You of course need to implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx), alternatively you can bind to new dependency properties on which you can register property changed callbacks).

Even easier:

```
var desc = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(RadioButton.IsCheckedProperty, typeof(RadioButton));
desc.AddValueChanged(_radioButton1, (_,__) =>
    {
        var isChecked = (bool)_radioButton1.IsChecked;
        //...
    });
```